# Why can I not view my files in external HDD?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a desktop computer with windows7 64b and a virtual machine with windows XP 32b, sometimes I need to get into the virtual machine and use my external HDD in order to use some files, evertything was working fine until today, where I tried to get a file in my host machine (windows7) but all the files were gone, I check the space usage on properties and half of the disk is in use, I open the HDD in the virtual machine and I can see the files, but in windows 7 I can't, it doesn't matter if I turn off the virtual machine or not!

Edit:

After some times connecting and desconnecting it works aparently normal!

Comment: How are you sharing the external drive with the VM? USB redirect? Shared folder?

Comment: USB directly! @RandolphWest